# Diamond printing code Kata

Tags: beginner, ocaml

the code implements this code kata: https://codingdojo.org/kata/Diamond/
This is my very first ocaml program, looking for any kind of feedback, as I'm a total ocaml noob.

It uses JaneStreet's Base and Stdio as well as cmdliner.

```ml
open Base
open Printf
open Stdio
open Cmdliner

exception DiamondError of string

let ascii_a = Char.to_int 'A'

let const_init_list n elem = 
  List.init n ~f: (fun _ -> elem)

let make_line depth i = if depth = 1 then
  ['A']
else 
  let line_width = 2 * depth - 1 in
  if i = 0 then 
    let dots = const_init_list ((line_width - 1) / 2) ' ' in
    dots @ ['A'] @ dots
  else
    let n_inner_dots = (i - 1) * 2 + 1 in
    let n_outer_dots = (line_width - n_inner_dots - 2) / 2 in
    let outer_dots = const_init_list n_outer_dots ' ' in
    let inner_dots = const_init_list n_inner_dots ' ' in
    let char_list = [Char.of_int_exn (ascii_a + i)] in
    outer_dots @ char_list @ inner_dots @ char_list @ outer_dots

let get_upper_triangle d = 
  List.init d ~f: (fun i -> make_line d i |> String.of_char_list) 

let render_diamond letter = 
  let triangle_depth = Char.to_int letter - ascii_a + 1 in
  if triangle_depth < 0 || triangle_depth > 26 then
    raise @@ DiamondError (sprintf "%c is invalid" letter)
  else 
    let upper_triangle = get_upper_triangle triangle_depth in
    if triangle_depth > 1 then 
      upper_triangle @ (List.tl_exn @@ List.rev upper_triangle)
    else
      upper_triangle
  
let main letter = 
  let diamond = try render_diamond letter  with 
    DiamondError s -> print_endline(s); Stdlib.exit 1 
  in 
  List.iter ~f: print_endline diamond

let letter  = 
  let doc = "The letter that determines which diamond is printed" in
  Arg.(required & pos 0 (some char) None & info [] ~doc ~docv:"LETTER")

let render_diamond_t = Term.(const main $ letter)
let cmd = Cmd.v (Cmd.info "diamond") render_diamond_t
let () = Stdlib.exit @@ Cmd.eval cmd
```

Comment: Minor note: in `const_init_list` you can replace `(fun _ -> elem)` with `(Fn.const elem)` from Base or `(Fun.const elem)` from Stdlib.

Comment: I had a feeling this function must exist, but didn't find it. Thanks :)